# get data from JSONP javascript

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I've got JSONP server response:

```
({"Info":"([["xxx",false,"",2,false,null],["yyy","zzzi","123456789","example@com","http://www.e-yyy.pl","example@com","img.jpg",null],["os","aaa","bbb","ccc",null,null,null],["xx_2012","www",2012,2012,2,[["yy_2012",null],["zz_2012",[["dk2","ccc1",1,123.5,null]]]]]])"})
```

How can I get example@com from it?

Comment: How do you read a property from an object?

Comment: strip off the `()` around it, then it's just json, and you can use a json lib to decode it back to a native JS structure.

Comment: Please provide more context. That's invalid JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval(), despite it have security problems.
Example:

```
//sample
var response_data = '({"Info": 1})';
alert(eval(response_data).Info);
```

But I think the best is to strip the () and use JSON.parse, as said in the comments section.